# Did Francois Valentijn say that Malay language in 16th century was understood by even people living in Persia and beyond?

Tags: language, malaysia

Utusan Malaysia, a mainstream newspaper publisher in Malaysia, published an [article](http://ww1.utusan.com.my/utusan/info.asp?y=2006&dt=0305&pub=Utusan_Malaysia&sec=Rencana&pg=re_01.htm) ( in Malay language) that claims that Malay language was a dominant and international language in 16th century. Straight from [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fww1.utusan.com.my%2Futusan%2Finfo.asp%3Fy%3D2006%26dt%3D0305%26pub%3DUtusan_Malaysia%26sec%3DRencana%26pg%3Dre_01.htm&edit-text=)

> Dutch scholar Francois Valentijn reveal Malay niche in the 16th
>   century as follows:
>
> **Their language, Malay**, spoken not only in coastal areas, **but also
>   in the rest of the archipelago and in the countries of the East, as a
>   language that is understood everywhere by everyone**, just like French
>   or Latin in Europe, or as a lingua franca in Italy and in the Levant.
>   Really wide spread of the Malay language that is not possible if we
>   understand we lost track, b**ecause the language is not only understood
>   in Persia even farther from it, and just to the east up the Philippine
>   archipelago.**

**One million dollar question: did Dutch scholar [Francois Valentijn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Valentijn) actually stay that? And if yes, where and when?**

It should be noted that the Malaysians who know better often take *Utusan*'s reporting and opinions with a grain of salt, not least because it has a long history of manipulating the facts to suit a certain agenda and and of even telling downright lies. But in this case, we should examine the claim on a case by case basis and forget for a moment whether *Utusan* is a trustworthy news outlet.

Comment: @jeroenk The claims seems to be about the **Malay language** in the 16th century, not about when Valentijn's book was published.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was quoted from Amin Sweeney's "[A Full Hearing: Orality and Literacy in the Malay World](https://books.google.com.my/books/about/A_Full_Hearing.html?id=Osit7YI8FWEC&redir_esc=y)" (1987).
Francois Valentijn was credited for translating the Bible into Ambon Malay, sometime during the 17th century.

Comment: It would be useful to include a link to a source that verifies your reference (e.g. google Books).

Comment: Link: http://www.ucpress.edu/op.php?isbn=9780520059108 or if you prefer Google Books: https://books.google.com.my/books/about/A_Full_Hearing.html?id=Osit7YI8FWEC&redir_esc=y